# pass a paramenter into object and use it for querySelector but return null

Tags: javascript

```
var ajaxFileUploader = function(formId){
    this.formId = formId;

    console.log(this.formId); //myForm
    return console.log(
        document.querySelector(this.formId)// null
    );
}

var foo = new ajaxFileUploader('#myFrom');
```

I try to create a object and pass a parameter into it.

it works fine when I console.log this property

but when I try to use querySelector, it return null

anyone know why it return null?

Comment: provide minimal information to debug your issue. Show us your html and relevant scripts

Comment: `return console.log(param)` gives `Illegal return statement` error

Comment: `return 
        document.querySelector(this.formId)`

Comment: @RobG `# ` already there `var foo = new ajaxFileUploader('#myFrom');`

Comment: use formId directly not this.formId

Comment: Are you sure the form exists when you call the function? (note typo in the call: '#myFrom'). Hey Xufox, just thought the same thing…

Comment: sry guys, i just notice, i have a typo from* -> form lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

enclose the whole code within `window.onload=function(){}`. you might have placed the script in head but the elements are at body thats why element loads late and script returns null. if you use `window.onload=function(){}` the script will run after the whole document once loaded

```js
window.onload=function(){
var ajaxFileUploader = function(formId){
    this.formId = formId;

    console.log(this.formId); //myForm
    return console.log(document.querySelector(this.formId));
}

var foo = new ajaxFileUploader('#myFrom');
  }
```

```html
<form id="myFrom" action="demo_form.asp" method="get">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: sry i just notice i have typo, i type form to from, took me many hours to find out, XD

Comment: ha haa... no issues ;)

Comment: then click on the `close` button in your question which will prevent users from trying answer it again and again

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with respect to context get lost of 'this'

**Solution 1:**

```
var ajaxFileUploader = function(formId){
    this.formId = formId;
    console.log(this.formId); 
    var logger = console.log.bind(this);
   return logger(
       document.querySelector(this.formId)
   );
}

var foo = new ajaxFileUploader('#myFrom');
```

**Solution 2:**

Another solution is you can use "formId" which will get by lexical context of function.